# CUDA cuFFT Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, c, macos, cuda, cufft

I'm trying to use cuFFT library but when I compile my project I have the error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_cufftDestroy" ...
"_cufftExecC2C" ...
"_cufftPlan1d" ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm using CUDA 7 and Eclipse Nsight on Mac OS X 10.10.3.
Other examples without cuFFT library correctly work. Are there other settings to do?

Answer (score 2):

I solved using the command line:

```
nvcc filename.cu -I/path_CUDA/include -L/path_CUDA/lib -lcufft
```

I surely think there is a configuration in Eclipse Nsight, but still I can't find it.

Comment: You can find the correct Eclipse configuration by looking at one of the CUFFT sample projects, such as simpleCUFFT.